# Facebook Marketing API: Is User in Audience?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Is there a way using the [Facebook Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis) (or GraphAPI) to verify that a given Facebook user (FBID given) is in an audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to know that someone is in an audience as this would expose information about that person.

However, you can create a Custom Audience using app scoped user IDs, and in this way you would have high certainty that the person is in the given audience.